# Write a method named "RollDie" that will return an integer in the range of 1 to 6

Tags: c#

Write a method named "RollDie" that will return an integer in the range of 1 to 6.

Comment: C or C#? Tag properly

Comment: C doesn't have methods.

Comment: You may start the title like **Function "RollDie"**. The term `method` is exclusive to languages like C++ and C#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>


int rolldie()
{
  time_t t;
  int ret=0;
    while(ret==0)
    {
      sleep(3); 
      /* You need some time to roll the die. Don't you? 
       * practically srand is not that random in close intervals
       * That is the practical use of sleep() here.
       */
      srand((unsigned)time(&t));//Initialize rand no gen
      ret=rand()%7;
    }
return ret;
}

int main()
{
int c=0;
  while(c<6)
  {
     printf("Rolling the die.. Result : %d\n",rolldie());
     c++;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user6233180 : You're welcome

Comment: yes can I ask other questions on private about C#?

Comment: @user6233180 : Yes, what prevents you from doing so? Ask a new question please and tag `C#`

Comment: Why is that downvote for?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there very simple code you just use the random method to generate your number then you can do what you want with it, you will probably simply return it or print the answer but that is up too you. (just saw you said return) ps. this is for c# not c unsure what you wanted since you said c# yet tagged c

```
public int DiceRoll()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int diceroll = rand.NEXT(1,7);
    return diceroll;
}
```